# RNFetchBlob download not working on android 9

Tags: android, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

My code to download the file as below

```
RNFetchBlob.config({
    path : path,
    background: true,
    cacheable:false,
    timeout: 1000 * 60 * 15 //15 minutes
})
.fetch('GET', forFile.url, {//some headers ..})
.then((res) => {
    Realm.open({
        schema: [
            ScheduleSchema,
            PlaylistSchema,
            FileSchema
        ],
        schemaVersion: schema_version
    }).then(realm => {
        realm.write(() => {
            localPath = Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file://' + res.path() : `playlists/${playlistName}/${getFileName(forFile)}`
            forFile.file_local_path = localPath
            console.log('The file saved to ', res.path() + 'for remote url' +forFile.url)

        })
    }).catch((error) => {
        alert("realm open error on file download service", error);
        console.log(error);
        reject(error)
    })
    resolve(forFile);
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("file download error " + error);
    showToastMessage(I18n.t("ErrorMessage.ErrorInFileDownload"))
})
```

This code works fine for Android 7 but not on Android 9.

Error from Android Studio Logcat as below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot make a new request because the previous response is still open: please call response.close()
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:164)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobReq$2.intercept(RNFetchBlobReq.java:385)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:172)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Any solution for this?